# Single number as xy coordinates

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm using a very specific random number generator to produce numbers between 0 and 2^20. I am trying to access elements of a two dimensional array using this number.

Because myArray[x][y] can be represented as myArray[x*a + y] (where 'a' is the number of elements in the second dimension), shouldn't I be able to turn my single random number into 2-dimensional coordinates? The array in question is 2^10 by 2^10 exactly, so I thought it would be:

```
int random = randomize();      //assigned a random value up to 2^20
int x = floor(random / pow(2, 10));
int y = random % pow(2, 10);
myArray[x][y] = something();   //working with the array
```

The arrays elements are not being accessed as predicted and some are not being accessed at all. I suspect a bug in my logic, I've checked my program's syntax.

No I can't use two random numbers to access the array.
No I can't use a one dimensional array.

Just checking this would be the correct math. Thank you.

Comment: `2^10` is 8, not 2¹⁰/1024.

Comment: [pow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/)...

Comment: @RyanJ If so, [`std::pow()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) please ...

Comment: `(2^10)` surely doesn't do what you think it does :P ...

Comment: @RyanJ: Using `pow()` is not a good approach for calculating power-of-2 values for integers. Bit-shift operations are much more efficient, easier, and do not suffer from rounding problems.

Comment: I was merely trying to address the general misunderstanding of the ^ operator, not specifically finding a power of 2. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanJ pow is not good for powers of 2. Use `1 << 10` instead

Comment: I'm very sorry! A typing error on my part. Post edited.

Comment: Due of the lack of comments on the operators i used to derive x and y I consider my question answered (if not in the way I expected).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `^` is a binary bitwise `XOR` operator, not a power operator.

An idiomatic expression for obtaining powers of 2 in C++ is `1 << n`, so you can rewrite your expression like this:

```
int x = floor(random / (1<<10));
int y = random % (1<<10);
```

The reason the left shift by `n` works like raising 2 to the power of `n` is the same that adding `n` zeros to one in a base-ten system multiplies the number by `n`-th power of ten.

Comment: integer division will be floored so no need to use `floor` either

Comment: A very useful tidbit, as it does not require a math oriented library like cmath.

Answer (score 0):

2^10 isn't 1024 in C++.

Because in c++ `^` is `XOR` (a bitwise operator ) [c++ operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators)

```
include <math.h>       /* pow */

int main ()
{
  int random = randomize();      //assigned a random value up to 2^20
  int x = floor(random / pow(2,10));
  int y = random % pow(2,10);
  myArray[x][y] = something();   //working with the array
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.